# Create dataframe of fixed size with dummy variables for numerical values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I must create the dummy variables for the column that could have 16 values (0-15), but not necessary has all 16 values when I create dummy variables based on it:

```
  my_column
0  3
1  4
2  7
3  1
4  9
```

I expect my dummy variables have 16 columns, or more - any another value that fixed by me in advance, and the number in the name of column corresponds to the value of `my_column`, but if my_column have only , let's say, 5 values from 16 possible values, the method `pd.get_dummies` will create only 5 columns (as expected from this method though) as following :

```
 my_column  1  3  4  7  9
0  3        0  1  0  0  0
1  4        0  0  1  0  0
2  7        0  0  0  1  0
3  1        1  0  0  0  0
4  9        0  0  0  0  1
```

How can I achieve one of the following results ?

```
 my_column   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
    0  3     0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1  4     0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2  7     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3  1     0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4  9     0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) + [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on the columns -

```
v = pd.get_dummies(df.my_column).reindex(columns=range(0, 16), fill_value=0)
```

According to the docs, `reindex` will -

> Conform DataFrame to new index with optional filling logic, placing
>   NA/NaN in locations having no value in the previous index.

`fill_value=0` will fill all missing columns with zeros.

You can add the original column to the result with `insert` or `concat` -

```
v.insert(0, 'my_column', df.my_column)
```

---

```
v = pd.concat([df, v], 1)   # alternative to insert
```

---

```
v

   my_column  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15
0          3  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1          4  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2          7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3          1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4          9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: could you please explain reindex also in your anwer ?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks